# Rolling up on a date for a column value in sql

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table `FRUIT_PRICE` which maintains prices of fruits on a daily basis.

```
Date          |    Fruit         |    Price
-----------------------------------------------------
2015-06-04         Banana             10
2015-06-04         Apple              20
2015-06-04         Orange             15 
2015-06-03         Orange             18
2015-06-03         Banana             9
2015-06-02         Banana             11
2015-06-02         Orange             16
2015-06-02         Apple              22
2015-06-02         Papaya             40
-----------------------------------------------------
```

It is entirely possible that some days price of some fruits are not populated. For e.g. price of Papaya is not available on 3rd and 4th June, price of apple is not available on 3rd June, etc.

I have another table `FRUIT_QTY` which maintains quantity of fruit on daily  basis.

```
Date          |    Fruit         |    QTY
-----------------------------------------------------
2015-06-04         Banana             100
2015-06-04         Apple              50
2015-06-04         Orange             150 
2015-06-04         Papaya             200 
2015-06-03         Orange             50
2015-06-03         Banana             100
2015-06-03         Apple              150
2015-06-03         Papaya             100 
2015-06-02         Banana             200
2015-06-02         Orange             150
2015-06-02         Apple              50
2015-06-02         Papaya             200
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I want to calculate `TOTAL_COST` (which is `Price * Qty`) on a given day.

I wrote below query for the same:

```
SELECT 
   A.DATE, A.FRUIT, (B.PRICE*A.QTY) AS TOTAL_COST 
FROM 
   FRUIT_QTY A INNER JOIN FRUIT_PRICE B ON A.FRUIT = B.FRUIT AND A.DATE = B.DATE 
  WHERE
     A.DATE = '2015-06-04'
```

This will obviously ignore the fruits for which `Price` is not available on given `Date`.

How can I modify the inner join between the two tables in above query such that if for a `Date` `Price` for a `Fruit` is not available, then previous `Date` should be checked and `Price` taken if available. If `Price` is not available on previous `Date`, the `Date` previous to previous `Date` should be checked and `Price` taken if available.

I want to continue checking for price for 30 days from given `Date`. `Fruit` should be ignored only if `Price` is not available for past 30 `Dates`.

I modified above query as below but then am stuck:

```
SELECT 
   A.DATE, A.FRUIT, (B.PRICE*A.QTY) AS TOTAL_COST 
FROM 
   FRUIT_QTY A 
       INNER JOIN 
   (sub query here to get first available price in last 30 days 
     starting from given date in where condition) as B ON  A.FRUIT = B.FRUIT 
  WHERE
     A.DATE = '2015-06-04'
```

How will be the sub query above to get first available price for a `Fruit` starting from given Date and rolling over up to 30 days until `Price` is found?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: @Downvoter: Please care to explain the reason for down voting!

Comment: Note that I'd assume there are cases where you don't get updated fruit quantities either... also, what platform and version of DB2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subquery to find the desired row within the date range:

```
B.Date = 
   ( SELECT MAX(C.Date)
     FROM FRUIT_PRICE AS C
     WHERE C.Date BETWEEN A.Date - 30 DAY AND A.Date
     AND A.Fruit = C.Fruit  )
```